# how many strings can be allocated

Tags: c#

I'm getting confused in my Dataset and XML code so I am backtracking to structures.

```
public struct UserID_Structure
{
    long ID = 0;
    char[] Login = new char[30];
    char[] eMail = new char[100];
    bool eMailVerified = false;
    char[] Authority = new char[10];
    DateTime DateRegistered = new DateTime();
    DateTime DateRecent = new DateTime();
    int LoginCount = 0;
    char[] ActivityFile = new char[20];
}
```

I'll just use a list instead of linkage.
But with the additional structures for addresses and personal information I am going to have a lot of char[] or strings.  Will the count crap out at a little more than 32k or 64k or 4 billion and are they both the same?

I remember there was a time when MS updated to 64 bit but left all the internal counters at 32.

Comment: Why don't you use **string**?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Is this interop code? Why do you need a structure at all?

Comment: If you were confused by DataSets then you will be flabbergasted by mutable structs and `char[]`. Better forget about this 'solution'.

Comment: Well, thanks.
The next structure, the address has twenty text 'strings'.
As far as I know, there is a limit to the number of strings that can be allocated and although that number can be increased in the configuration, not sure how but found it once, there must be a lot of maintenance and at a large number it could go slower, sooner, with a good number of allocated strings.
So even though some space is wasted, there is only one allocation for the structure and the fields are addressed by offsets, so allocation is 20 to 1 strings vrs. structure.

More like 150 to 4. mutable/pointers ok

Comment: You are implementing a broken solution for a non-existing problem.